# Checking for 'gee-0.8' >= 0.8.0 : not found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install pysoy and at the stage of configuration using

`./waf configure`

it gives an error as seen below

---

```
Checking for 'gee-0.8' >= 0.8.0          : not found

The configuration failed

(complete log in /home/mylap/Documents/coding/pysoy/libsoy/build/config.log)
```

---

I think this needs `libgee` needs to be installed..

My attempt to install `libgee`:

1. downloaded libgee-0.11.4 from net
2. set workspace to that directory and i ran `./configure`
3. `./configure` executed succesfully
4. ran `make` command and encountered this error :

---

```
mylap@mylap-Inspiron-N5110:~/libgee-0.11.0$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mylap/libgee-0.11.0'
Making all in gee
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mylap/libgee-0.11.0/gee'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mylap/libgee-0.11.0/gee'
Making all in tests
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mylap/libgee-0.11.0/tests'
  CCLD     tests
../gee/.libs/libgee-0.8.so: error: undefined reference to 'g_get_num_processors'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tests] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mylap/libgee-0.11.0/tests'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mylap/libgee-0.11.0'
make: *** [all] Error
```

---

5. I couldn't find answer for  " undefined reference to `g_get_num_processors` 
   Please help

(Also, can someone add tag `pysoy` to this question. I don't have the privilege to make new tags..)

Comment: per my comment below, which Ubuntu are you on/using?

Answer (score 8):

Please install first these packages:

```
libgee-0.8-2
libgee-0.8-dev
```

You can install them with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgee-0.8-2 libgee-0.8-dev
```

Or with this other:

```
sudo apt-get install libgee-0.8*
```

Comment: I tried..got this error 
E: Unable to locate package libgee-0.8-2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgee-0.8-2'
E: Unable to locate package libgee-0.8-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgee-0.8-dev'

Comment: In my computer with Ubuntu [tag:14.04] works perfectly. Did you ran it copying/pasting or typing? However, I edited my post, try the second command.

Comment: @Raje Which version of Ubuntu are you using?  [`libgee-0.8` and its packages are only available in Trusty and later](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgee-0.8) and unless you are on Ubuntu Trusty or later you won't be able to easily get those dependencies.